# how to use regex serde for :: as delimiter in file

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have a data set which uses double colons (`::`) as a delimiter.  How can I use regex serde in Hive to parse the data so that it can be imported into a table?

Data structure is as below:

```
userId::movieId::rating::time
```

Currently I am using this query, but it gives nulls for select statements:

```
create table rating_regex(userId string,movieId string,rating string,time string) row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' with serdeproperties(
"input.regex" = "::"
  ) stored as textfile
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a full regular expression for the entire record, and then declare the output format.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE rating_regex(
  userId string,
  movieId string,
  rating string,
  time string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH serdeproperties("input.regex" = "(.+)::(.+)::(.+)::(.+)",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s")
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot JamCon, and congrats for 1K.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to previously good answer. you can also use multidelimitserde in case you have multiple delimiters in your input file.

Suppose you want to load below input file to you hive table.

```
userId::movieId::rating::time
1111::Rambo::one::2016-01-04 00:12:06


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  UDB.movie_rating (
 userId        VARCHAR(10)
,movieId       VARCHAR(20) 
,rating        VARCHAR(5) 
,movietime     timestamp
)
comment 'This table will contain movie rating information.'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"="::")
LOCATION '/hdfspathlocation/MULTISERDE'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
;

select * from UDB.movie_rating;

+---------+----------+---------+------------------------+--+
| userid  | movieid  | rating  |       movietime        |
+---------+----------+---------+------------------------+--+
| 1111    | Rambo    | one     | 2016-01-04 00:12:06.0  |
+---------+----------+---------+------------------------+--+
```